# Como saber quais são elementos que estão antes e depois de um determinado elemento no array?

Tags: javascript

eu tenho um array:

```
Const array = [1,”a”,3];
```

Eu quero saber como posso verificar quais são elementos que estão antes e depois do “a”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com um simples `.indexOf` você pega a posição do item, então subtraindo por 1 você pega o item anterior e somando +1 você pega o item posterior:

```js
const array = [1,"a",3];

var pos = array.indexOf("a");
var antes = array[pos-1];
var depois = array[pos+1];

console.log(antes, depois);
```

Comment: e pra pegar o antes do depois?

Comment: Hãã? Não entendi

Comment: resposta certa:  var antesdodepois = array[pos-1+1]; ou var antesdodepois = array[pos-0]; hahaha ou simplesmente var antesdodepois = array[pos];

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar as funções [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) e [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
const array = [1,"a",3]
const arrayReduzida = array.filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return index < array.indexOf("a")
})
```

No exemplo acima, a variável `arrayReduzida` vai possuir o valor `[1]` cuja posição é menor do que a posição do elemento `2`. Você poderia também utilizar a magia das arrows functions e ter:

```
const array = [1,"a",3]
const teste = array.filter((value, index, array) => index < array.indexOf("a"))
```

Que tem o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Obrigado Joao, voce me ajudou bastante, mas eu tenho uma duvida.. caso eu tenha o array [1,2,”a”,3] e queira retornar so 2? Pelo o que eu entendi do seu código, ele retorna o 1,2 correto?

Comment: Você fala retornar só 2? A função filter vai te retornar um novo array com todos os componentes do antigo array que passem um determinado teste. Logo, caso você tenha o array `[1,2,”a”,3]`, o código acima vai te voltar `[1,2]`. Se você quisesse que ele voltasse apenas `[2]` você teria que fazer uma modificação na condicional, que, nesse caso, deixaria de ser `index < array.indexOf("a")` e passaria a ser `index < array.indexOf("a") && value == 2`. Note que nos parâmetros, `value` é o valor salvo no array, `index` a posição e `array` o array que está sendo iterado.